# Why is my code from codepen not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've copied the code from my codepen into atom and saved it. I think i've correctly added the jquery script and linked the stylesheets but my page is still displayed different when I open from local.

Codepen - http://codepen.io/jordan_miguel/pen/gLwJRb

Browser view

[image]

This is my console error

[image]

Folder structure[image]

Html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>

  <body>
  <main id="main">
  <nav class="nav">
  <a href="#" class="nav-item active" data-rel="project">Jordan Miguel</a>
<!-- when clicked will go to the option, so projects have to be the required option-->
<a href="#" class="nav-item" data-rel="option-2">Personal</a>
<a href="#" class="nav-item" data-rel="option-2">CV</a>
<a href="#" class="nav-item" data-rel="option-3">Contact</a>
     </nav>

      <ul class="portfolio">
      <li class="project option-1">
     <div class="project-image"><a href="default.asp"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/" alt="Sports Image" />
    <p>some text to display here</p>
    </div>
     <div class="project-info">
    <h2 class="project-info-title">Cricket Journey</h2>
    </a>
    </div>
   </li>

  <li class="project option-2">
  <div class="project-image"><a href="default.asp"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/2/" alt="Sports Image" />
    </div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h2 class="project-info-title">Swim</h2>
    </a>
    </div>
 </li>

<li class="project option-3">
  <div class="project-image"><a href="default.asp"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/3/" alt="Sports Image" /></div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h2 class="project-info-title">Tour De Force</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="project option-2">
  <div class="project-image"><a href="default.asp"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/10/" alt="Sports Image" /></div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h2 class="project-info-title">Baseball Season</h2>
   </div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="project option-3">
  <div class="project-image"><a href="default.asp"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/5/" alt="Sports Image" /></div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h2 class="project-info-title">BMX Arrives</h2>
    </div>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="project option-1">
  <div class="project-image"><a href="default.asp"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/6/" alt="Sports Image" /></div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h2 class="project-info-title" href="#">World Cup 2016</h2>
   </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Css

```
    body {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 450;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
    margin: 0 5px;
    }


   a {
   text-decoration: none !important;
   }

   #main {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
   -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
   -webkit-box-pack: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    margin: 0 auto;
      }

    .nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
   -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
   -webkit-box-pack: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
     padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    }

   .nav-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 450;
     color: #a6a6a6;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }

   .nav-item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
   height: 2px;
   background: #595959;
   -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
   transition: all 500ms;
   }
   .nav-item.active {
    color: black;
   -webkit-transition: all 350ms;
    transition: all 350ms;
    }

   .portfolio {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 6;
    list-style: none;
    }

  .project {
   position: relative;
   flex: 1 0 calc(100% - 20px);
   margin: 10px;

    &:hover {
    .project-info {
    }
    }

    @media (min-width: 520px) {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 2) - 20px);
    }

@media (min-width: 860px) {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
}
}

 .project-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 padding: 30px;
 }


  p {
 /* position the text */
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
  }
  img:hover + p {
  display: block;
  }
```

JS

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
$('.nav-item').click(function(){
    // reset active class
    $('.nav-item').removeClass("active");
    // add active class to selected
    $(this).addClass("active");
    // return needed to make function work
    return false;
});


$(function() {
    // create an empty variable
    var selectedClass = "";
    // call function when item is clicked
    $(".nav-item").click(function(){
        // assigns class to selected item
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel");
        // fades out all portfolio items
        $(".portfolio li").fadeOut(300);
        // fades in selected category
        $(".portfolio li." + selectedClass).delay(300).fadeIn(300);
    });
});

}); // document ready
```

Comment: check the console error,

Comment: Use your browser's console to see if there are errors.

Comment: How is it displayed differently? Is it poor styling? Is the content stacked all together on top of itself? Add a screenshot. We don't know what we're looking for.

Comment: @mmativ check the update, i posted a picture of the error

Comment: show your folder structure,

Comment: @mmativ see changes, still nothing is working

Comment: please show the entire console error

Comment: the error seems to have gone now... @mmativ

Comment: but the page is still displayed different

Comment: The problem is with your code. Somewhere in there you have something like `src=<script src=...`. This is what's throwing the error.

Comment: how can i rectify this? @k97513

Comment: Click on the error and it should show you the line with that error

Answer (score 1):

There is an **Export** button on bottom-right corner. Download your sample as it is by clicking this button.